# typolink on whole COA

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to set one link around all my Content Objects, so the whole content ist wrapped. So far I've tried something like this:

```
#Rendering start box text with image
ap_content.textpic.100  = COA
ap_content.textpic.100{
    wrap = <div class="start-box-wrapper link">|</div>
    10 = FILES
    10{               
        references{
            table = tt_content
            uid.field = uid
            fieldName = image
        }            
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj{
            wrap = <img class="lazy img-responsive" src="fileadmin/{$folderName}/Resources/Public/Images/loading-spin.svg"|/>

            11 = IMG_RESOURCE
            11{
                stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | data-src="|"|
                file{
                    import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
                    maxW{
                        if.isTrue.field = tx_t3webkit_retina
                        cObject = USER
                        cObject {
                            userFunc = usr_t3webkitHelpers->getImageDimensions
                            userFunc{
                                picture = IMG_RESOURCE
                                picture{
                                    file.import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid    
                                }
                                device = desktop
                                type = w
                            }
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
            12 = IMG_RESOURCE
            12{
                stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | data-src-retina="|"|
                file.import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
            }
            13 = TEXT
            13{
                data = file:current:name
                replacement{
                    10 = TEXT
                    10{
                        search.cObject = TEXT
                        search.cObject{
                            wrap = .|
                            data = file:current:extension
                        }
                        replace =
                    }
                }
                override.data = file:current:alternative
                stdWrap{
                    required = 1
                    noTrimWrap = | alt="|"|
                }   
            }
        } 
    }
    20 = COA
    20{
```

##################### HERE IS THE PROBLEM ##################

```
 stdWrap {
        innerWrap = <div class="start-box-bg"><div class="start-box-txt">|</div></div>
        typolink.parameter = 3
        } 


        23 = TEXT   
        23{
            field = header
            wrap = <h4>|</h4>
            replacement{
                10{
                    search = |
                    replace = &shy;
                }
            }    
        }
        24 = TEXT
        24{
            field = bodytext
            parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE
        }
        25 = TEXT
        25{
            data = LLL:fileadmin/{$folderName}/Resources/Private/Language/template.xml:content.stratbox.link
            typolink{
                parameter.field = header_link
                ATagParams = class="btn"
            }
        }

    }
    30 = TEXT
    30{
        wrap = <div class="teaser"><h4>|</h4></div>
        field = header
        replacement{
            10{
                search = |
                replace = &shy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't produce the desired outcome, what's wrong?
he is closing the a tag or he wraps just the content and not the whole div:

```
<div class="start-box-wrapper link">
<img ... />
<!-- this content is sliding over the image -->
    <a href="header_link"> header text</a>
    <div class="start-box-bg" style="left: -100%;">
    <div class="start-box-txt">
    <a href="header_link">
    <h4>header</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="header_link">
    <p class="bodytext">Lorem Ipsum </p>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Despite the fact that your code style is not the best, the object does work. I've copied your code and cleaned it up a bit (just removed the commented code). In my case the following output is generated: <a href="/de/kontakt/"><div class="start-box-bg"><div class="start-box-txt"><h4>Test</h4></div></div></a>. I've only switched "field = header" to "value = Test". Your TS should at least render the divs. Could you please describe the problem/ output a little bit better?

Comment: it is? in my case he is always closing the <a> tag

Comment: Yes, it works for me. We should start isolating the problem. Please remove all static TypoScript templates and everything. Reset your root TypoScript template and paste the following TS:

`page = PAGE
page {
  typeNum = 0
  10 = COA
  10 {
    stdWrap.innerWrap = <div class="start-box-bg"><div class="start-box-txt">|</div></div>
    stdWrap.typolink.parameter = 3

    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      value = Test
      wrap = <h4>|</h4>
    }
  }
}`

What does it produce?

Comment: is it also wrapping with one <a> tag if u add more objects than just one <h4>?

Comment: Yes, please see my compley example below. I've added it to an answer since the word wrapping is not very nice in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case, the problem is caused by invalid HTML. The complex TypoScript code generates nested a-tags. The browser's console does not show the "correct" HTML output. The HTML source code shows the nesting. So removing the inner a-tag solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet generates the desired output. It is tested with TYPO3 7.6.x.

```
page = PAGE
page {
  typeNum = 0

  10 = COA
  10 {
    stdWrap {
      innerWrap = <div class="start-box-bg"><div class="start-box-txt">|</div></div>
      typolink.parameter = 3
    }

    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      value = Test
      wrap = <h4>|</h4>
    }

    20 = TEXT
    20 {
      value = More text to go with lorem ipsum.
      wrap = <p>|</p>
    }
  }
}
```

The generated HTML looks as follows:

```
<a href="index.php?id=3">
  <div class="start-box-bg">
    <div class="start-box-txt">
      <h4>Test</h4>
      <p>More text to go with lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Based on the given code snippet of the author, the following HTML is generated:

```
<div class="start-box-wrapper link">
    <a href="index.php?id=3">
        <div class="start-box-bg">
            <div class="start-box-txt">
                <h4>Title &shy;&shy; mit Separator</h4>
                Ich <link 38>bin</link> <b>Bodytext</b>.<a href="index.php?id=28" class="btn">Test</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="teaser"><h4>Title &shy;&shy; mit Separator</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could it might be a problem with my version? Im using 6.2.13

Comment: I tried the code in a new project and yes, it works. But now i can understand even less why the tag is closing itself... Im editing my code so the you can see the whole class.

Comment: I've tested my example with TYPO3 6.2.14. It works as expected. Tonight I can review your complex snippet.

Comment: could be something wrong in my configuration? like in the RTE ? im not very experienced with that one either.

Comment: Okay, I've tested your TypoScript and found some misconcepts. TYPO3 is behaving correctly. Please do not analyze your code via your browser console (F12). Instead, analyze the "real" source code. You will see that your a tag is rendered correctly, but it's not valid HTML. You're having a-tags inside the outer a-tag. This is not valid. Your cObjects .24 and .25 are generating these links/ problems. So you have to re-think your concept.

Comment: thats correct, thank you very much. After i deleted the inner a-tag the issue was solved. pls write it as an answer so i can close this one.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reply. New answer is added and we are done :)